# Wait time between web elements [Webdriverwait Selenium]

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to place time gap between each web element.
For example i want first webelement should work after 10 seconds and second web element should work after 30 seconds.But thats not working for me.

**And is that possible if element1 i clicked manually then 2nd will work automatically, because in current case if i click 1st one manually then 2nd element not working automatically.**

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
            driver.get("http://demo.com");
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 600);
            // First path
                        WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[5]/div/input")));
                        element1.click();
                        // Second path
                        WebElement element2 = wait.until(
                                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='sbt67Pin']")));
                        element2.click();
                        // Third path
```

Comment: You misunderstood what `WebDriverWait` does. For fixed wait you can use `sleep`.

Comment: Yes i know thats for overall process , but what i should use for individual element? and where i should use, can you write down please?

Comment: @Punjabii I wrote in my comment, to always wait 10 seconds you need to use `sleep`.

Comment: @KunduK implicit wait won't wait for 10 seconds, it behaves similar to `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: @Guy: you are right.Sorry for the wrong comment.he wants to keep the scripts halt for some times.so `Thread.sleep()` required in that case.

Comment: @KunduK how i can use Thread.sleep() in element row instead of wait.until

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Thread.sleep()` like that.If want to halt your scripts running.

```
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[5]/div/input"));
  element1.click();
  hread.sleep(20000);
  // Second path
  WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sbt67Pin']"));
  element2.click();
  // Third path
  Thread.sleep(30000);
```